# MySQL Cluster with Memcache Support

Tags: mysql, caching, memcached, cluster-computing, high-availability

I've been reading up about MySQL Cluster 7, and it appears that there is some support for a memcache storage engine.

Does the implemenation require any custom code in the application (making requests to memcache), or is it integrated to the point where I could

```
select cars.* from cars WHERE cars.id = 100
```

and MySQL cluster + memcache would be able to "automatically" look at the memcache cache first, and if there wasn't a hit, look in MySQL?

Like wise with update - Would i manually have to set the data in memcache with every modify or is there a mechanism that will do it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memcached would not provide the functionality that you describe. Memcached is key-value storage, and it does not automatically cache any query results. You would need to write code to store the results. Some frameworks make this easier.

MySQL's query caching can cache query results, but you're still hitting MySQL.

MySQL's NDB cluster is a clustered in-memory storage engine that is able to serve up relational data very fast thanks to load balancing and partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog to learn more about the implementation and capabilities of the memcached API for MySQL Cluster:
http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/scalabale-persistent-ha-nosql-memcache-storage-using-mysql-cluster/

Essentially the API is implemented as a plug-in to the memcached server which can then communicate directly with the data nodes, via memcached commands, without going through an SQL layer - giving you very fast native access to your data, with full persistence, scalability, write throughput and schema or schemaless data storage